# Are communicability and verifiability the only reasons to prohibit other true results?

Tags: publishability, science, community, science-communication

In order to publish a research paper in a particular domain, or the domain itself must satisfy the above two requirements: *Communicable to and verifiable by other people*. Isn't it?

In this context, I got a doubt that the content of research papers are limited by objectivity and results that cannot be either uncommunicable or unverifiable are considered off topic and are never encouraged in the either academic or the scientific community.

Isn't it limiting the scientific development that can reach such truths also?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by 'subjective truth'? How would any scientific field benefit from publishing what a single individual believes to be true, without presenting any proof?

Comment: Subjective truth I m referring are subjective experienced such as life review, out of body experience etc..,

Comment: There are other formats of non-fiction texts, which might be better suitable than a research article in such cases. For example biographies, reports or a critical analysis of a topic. Research papers have strict purpose and thus also defined rules

Comment: So, in your model, would you say that the subjective experience of mass psychosis would qualify as a research result?

Comment: @Captain Emacs No, I'm asking why the scientific community is restricted to communicability and provability although no one can prove that the truths can be objective only.

Comment: @hangum There is a school of thought (qv. Karl Popper) which states a result is scientific not if it's provable, but if it can be shown to be invalid (falsifiable). Unfortunately a single person's unrepeatable experiences still wouldn't qualify.

Comment: There is something that we consider "grounding". It is the ability to perform experiments, largely independent from where we are and get consistent results. Of course, when that fails (and it can fail, especially if theory is required to validate the experiments and that theory is at the limits of its expressiveness), then there is a problem. But in principle, the rules of semiconductors, lasers, gravity etc. should work equally independently of the experimenter. There is no such transferability for "subjective" experiences - perhaps it will change if we understand the brain better?

Comment: Seems very abstract.  Hard to grasp.  Give us a little flavor of a specific example (preferably the one that provoked the question).  We can still generalize afterwards but as written the question is too general and theoretical to engage.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to remember that science is not the only form of research. Second, subjective results come in all sorts of flavors. If I ask one person person if they like A better than B, that is a subjective result. If I ask 1000 people, and do statistics, is that still a successful subjective result? Someone else could ask a new group of subjects the same question and verify my results.

Now consider an objective measure of a one time event (e.g., the amount of snow that fell during a storm). No one can verify the measurement, but it is still objective.